# Is there a React/Flux boilerplate project or generator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I recently started working with React.js and the Flux architecture. Being a relatively new framework I've had a hard time figuring out the recommended structure/naming/G an app.

Are there any React/Flux boilerplate projects? Generators to kickstart a new project?

Comment: I would really recommend https://github.com/apzentral/react-flux-router-boilerplate that is based on https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit. They are the working team on this project continuously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

https://github.com/banderson/generator-flux-react

Comment: How did I never come across this. Thanks!